# Using a managed buffer in native code after the call returns

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

I have a buffer I am allocating in C# and passing to native code. I then save a pointer to that buffer:

**Header Definitions**

```c++
// called when a meter is attached
typedef void(__cdecl * lpfnMeterAttachCallback)();

extern lpfnMeterAttachCallback frMeterAttachCallback;

// called when a meter is detached
typedef void(__cdecl * lpfnMeterDetachCallback)();

extern lpfnMeterAttachCallback frMeterDetachCallback;


// called when a meter is detached
typedef void(__cdecl * lpfnMeterReadCompleteCallback)();

extern lpfnMeterReadCompleteCallback frMeterReadCompleteCallback;

extern char* frbuffer;
```

**Main**

```c++
lpfnMeterAttachCallback frMeterAttachCallback;
lpfnMeterDetachCallback frMeterDetachCallback;
lpfnMeterReadCompleteCallback frMeterReadCompleteCallback;
char* frbuffer;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl InitDriver(
    lpfnMeterAttachCallback meterAttachCallback,
    lpfnMeterDetachCallback meterDetachCallback,
    lpfnMeterReadCompleteCallback meterReadCompleteCallback, char* buffer)
{
    frMeterAttachCallback = meterAttachCallback;
    frMeterDetachCallback = meterDetachCallback;
    frMeterReadCompleteCallback = meterReadCompleteCallback;
    frbuffer = buffer;
...
}
```

and later in a background call, fill it as so:

```
JSONValue testSS = ss->GetJSON();
std::string help = *testSS;
strcpy(frbuffer, help.c_str());
if (frMeterReadCompleteCallback) frMeterReadCompleteCallback();
```

However my string comes back empty, or as corrupted data. Ideally, I wanted to have a string passed back to my delegate and then use that, but ran into InterOp issues trying to do so.

**C#:**

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void InitDriver(MeterAttachCallback meterAttachCallback,
        MeterDetachCallback meterDetachCallback,
        MeterReadCompleteCallback meterReadCompleteCallback, StringBuilder sb);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void MeterAttachCallback();

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void MeterDetachCallback();


[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void MeterReadCompleteCallback();

static public void OnMeterAttach()
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnMeterAttach");
}

static public void OnMeterDetach()
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnMeterDetach");
}

static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10 * 1024 * 1024); //10MB

static public void OnMeterReadComplete()
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnMeterReadComplete; JSON:", sb.ToString());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    InitApolloCppDriver(OnMeterAttach, OnMeterDetach, OnMeterReadComplete, sb);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Am I writing/reading the buffer incorrectly, or should I be implementing this in a different way?

Comment: The marshaller in .NET will only keep the memory used by `sb` pinned (so that unmanaged code may access it) for the duration of the call to `InitDriver`, so that can't work. There are ways of doing it manually, but it's complicated. Passing the string in the callbacks seem like a better (and easier) solution. It will work provided you get the marshalling correct.

Comment: You can't hope to take a reference to this memory and expect it to mean anything after the function which was passed the reference returns. Think about it. How could the managed code deallocate the memory if it has no idea the unmanaged code is going to hold a reference to it. You need to rethink this. Start by removing the buffer. It is needless.

Comment: The InitDriver method is constantly running after invocation, acting as a server of sorts. The callback occurs while the 'server' is running, using the buffer passed to the function initially, filling it, then calls the callback while waiting for the next request.

Comment: So it doesn't return? The marshaller does it's magic after the function has returned, which in the case of `StringBuilder` would probably be to check and update the length of the contained string. So if the function doesn't return, that won't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this cannot work as intended.  The pinvoke marshaller has built-in knowledge about StringBuilder.  When you use it normally, it first pins the underlying buffer so it cannot move while the native code is running.  Then it makes the call to the native code and after that call completes it directly manipulates the members of the StringBuilder object to make it jive with the native string.

None of this is happening in your case, you party on the buffer *after* the pinvoke marshaller returned.  In other words, you are writing to a buffer whose address is not guaranteed to be stable.  That's very, *very* bad, debugging a corrupted GC heap is very unfun.  You do happen to get away with it in this specific case, the buffer is too large, next time you won't be so lucky.

And of course the internal members of StringBuilder don't get updated, getting an empty string is the expected outcome.

And the primary reason you should not be doing this, there is no conversion done from the 8-bit C-string characters you write (ANSI encoding assumed) to the utf-16 Unicode codepoints that a StringBuilder stores.  In other words, this is not an optimization at all, the string always needs to be copied.  The data corruption you see is a side effect of other code re-using the memory that was previously occupied by a temporary unmanaged buffer.  You didn't get to a point yet where you in turn corrupted the memory of, say, a bitmap.  Completely undiagnosable of course.

You need to throw this away.  Since copying is inevitable, you might as well have the native code allocate the buffer.

Comment: "You need to throw this away." That is so funny. That's going to be a standard sentence from now on.